# JENKINS - Changing Workspace root directory in Windows

Tags: windows, svn, jenkins

I have my checkout directory in E drive. But when I change the

```
Workspace root directory
```

or Custom workspace directory to E drive I get following error:

```
Building in workspace E:\SIMS_BRANCH_SVN
java.io.IOException: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect:
```

Perhaps due to colon. Can anyone help me?

Comment: At least it is working fine for me. I tried changing from `C:\dir` to `D:\anotherdir` and it worked fine. I have `Jenkins ver. 1.574` and i'm on Win 7.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it was my mistake. The relative checkout directory name was incorrect